# Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Hi have an SQL statement I need to LIMIT and just cant get the syntax right!

```
$strSQL = 'SELECT * FROM BlogItem WHERE Blog_Live=1 LIMIT '.$rowsperpage.' OFFSET '.$offset.''; $objQuery = mssql_query($strSQL)
or die ("Error Query [".$strSQL."]");
```

Can anyone give me some advice?

EDIT:

I am using SQL Server 2008

Tried this:

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM BlogItem WHERE Blog_Live=1 AND RowNum >= ".$offset." AND RowNum < ".$offset." + ".$rowsperpage."";
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using SQL Server? Because that's MySQL syntax you're using there. If it is SQL Server, this is a duplicate question, and hopefully you can use the newer `OFFSET` and `FETCH` mentioned in one of the answers of the duplicate I've marked....

Comment: What are the values of the variables `$rowsperpage` and `$offset`?

Comment: Try this for once. `$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM BlogItem WHERE Blog_Live=1 LIMIT $rowsperpage OFFSET $offset"; 
$objQuery = mssql_query($strSQL) or die ("Error Query [".$strSQL."]");`

Comment: Hi Matt, I have read the duplicate but am still not sure how to format my SQL Query, I am using SQL Server 2008! Any advice appreciated!

Comment: `OFFSET` and `FETCH` are only available in SQL Server 2012 onwards, I believe, so you'll have to use one of the more complex older syntaxes using `ROW_NUMBER()` like the accepted answer in that duplicate question. I'd say you should try doing that, and if you have a problem, ask a fresh question with the specifics of the problem you're having.

Comment: I cant post for another 90 minutes! The ROW_NUMBER() method I don't really understand looking at the example in the answer

Answer (score 0):

did you try like this

```
SELECT * FROM <table>
    ORDER BY <columns>
    OFFSET <EXPR1> ROWS
    FETCH NEXT <EXPR2> ROWS ONLY
```

Example :

```
SELECT * FROM t_book AS P
    ORDER BY P.barcode
    OFFSET 10 ROWS
    FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

or

```
;WITH Results_CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        Col1, Col2, ...,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SortCol1, SortCol2, ...) AS RowNum
    FROM Table
    WHERE <whatever>
)
SELECT *
FROM Results_CTE
WHERE RowNum >= @Offset
AND RowNum < @Offset + @Limit`
```